# How do I prove that if $A \neq B$, then $\{A\} \neq \{B\}$, where $A$, $B$ are sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axioms

This is in ZFC, and I thought it looked trivial, so I didn't give it much thought at first, but I've tried it now for some time with no progress.

I'd like to keep the proof as short as possible. Would really appreciate some hints :)

Comment: What does  = / = mean?

Comment: For sets to be the same, they must have the same elements.

Comment: @copper.hat the symbol $\neq$ means *is not equal to* or *does not equal*. It is simply putting a slash through the equals sign $=$ as a way of “crossing it out” $\neq$ and striking out the fact that both terms or expressions on either side of the equation are *not* equal to each other as opposed to being equal. Like how the symbol $\exists x$ denotes *there exists an $x$-value* and $\nexists x$ denotes *there does not exist an $x$-value*.

Comment: @user477343: Thanks for the explanation, I understand the usual symbols. The original question had the symbol = / =, not $\neq$.

Comment: @copper.hat oh sorry. I thought you meant $\neq$ because I don’t see $= / =$ anywhere in the post. Perhaps it was edited.

Comment: @user477343: That's funny, I thought you were joking at first, then realised that you were being helpful, which I appreciate.

Comment: @copper.hat hah well you are right. I wasn’t. I looked at your profile and realised your level at maths, so all sorted now :)

Comment: @user477343: Been a while since I've seen them referred to as maths :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by contradiction: $$\text{ if } \{A\}=\{B\} \text{ then }A=\bigcup \{A\}=\bigcup\{B\}=B$$

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $A\in \{A\}$ and $A\not\in \{B\}$